# What is the target .NET Framework of ESRI ArcObjects SDK 10.2

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, arcgis-desktop, .net, add-in

I had ArcMap 10 Add-In project built with ArcObjects SDK for .NET 10.1 where I could not reference external COM DLL build on .NET 4.0 due to a .NET forward compatibility issue. (ArcObjects SDK 10.1 uses .NET 3.5 SP1)

I wonder if the newer ArcObjects SDK 10.2 release targets the .NET 4.0 framework.
That will solve my problem.

Does anyone know?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.Net 4 is supported by ArcGIS 10.1, but there is a little extra work you will need to do.  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000nzv000000

> If you require any of the .NET 4.0 Framework functionality, you can
>   extend Esri products with components written in the .NET 4.0
>   Framework. However, it's your responsibility to redistribute and/or
>   verify that the .NET 4.0 Framework exists on the target system.

Answer (score 4):

[According to the official documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#//01510000006n000000):

> ArcGIS for Desktop, ArcGIS Engine, or ArcGIS for Server is required to develop with ArcObjects SDK.
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1

Answer (score 2):

I installed the 10.2 and created ArcMapAddin test project. It seems it targets the .Net 4.0 by default.

[image: VS2010 ArcMapAddin project]

The 10.2 ArcMap.exe.config is not targeting .NET 4.0 by default:
[image: ArcMap.exe.config 10.2]

In Win7 32 bit the ArcMap.exe.config is located at C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin\

It needs to be manually changed to
[image]

Comment: Though it is an older post, but I really need arcobjects sdk v10.2 for .NET. How you built this "ArcMapAddin test project"?? I have vs2010 and arcmap for desktop v10.2. but I cannot build any arcmapAddin projects because of sdk ..If you can, pls help.Thanks.